# Uncaught type error cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, local-storage, crud

I have an Issue,I was working on a Contact app where I used local storage b4 I recently changed pc and transfered my vscode folders to new Pc,but I am getting uncaught error type cannot read properties of null (reading 'push') when I try to run code on  new Pc . lost all previous saved contacts.please what do I do.

Comment: What are you attempting to push to? Please include your code so we can see what's actually happening.

Comment: Push to array and save to local-storage.

Comment: Does the array exist at runtime? We have no context; you need to include your code.

Comment: My major issue is not the deleted contacts but I can't add contacts.I am sort of a beginner,so I don't really understand some technical terms you might be asking like runtime.But from my little experience,as long as it was a working code ,it should still work by adding and displaying my new contacts on new Pc.As for adding code,I'm always stressed out whenever I try to do so here, probably I can share the code with you on another channel, so you get my point

Answer (score 0):

Your local storage exists only in that browser and in that machine. So if for example you are running chrome in your old pc, then that data will exists only there.

Probably you were storing an array of contacts in your previous machine, so now that you are running that code in a new machine you are receiving a `null`.

I recommend you to first check if your data exists in local storage, if not then initialize a new array and store it.

```js
// examples
const getContactsFromLocalStorage = () => {
  const contacts = localStorage.getItem("contacts");
  if (!contacts) {
    localStorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify([]));
    return [];
  }

  return JSON.parse(contacts);
};

const saveNewContactToLocalStorage = (contact) => {
  const contacts = localStorage.getItem("contacts");

  const parsedContacts = contacts ? JSON.parse(contacts) : [];

  parsedContacts.push(contact);

  localStorage.setItem("contacts", parsedContacts);
};
```

Comment: No my data doesn't exist in local storage of new machine.what do you mean by initialize a new array in this context?..Do you mean changing array name or ?

Comment: Having the same issue with TO DO APP I built

Comment: I added some examples, i hope that helps you

Comment: Gonzalo ..you know what..send me your email,so I send you the code to understand what I'm really talking about .I always have issues whenever I try to enter code here.

Comment: My major issue is that I can't save and display new contacts,at least since code worked on former Pc ,It should work on new Pc..